# How can I delete a user inputed element/data from an Array in Structure?

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm really new in C Programming  (only 3 days and stil learning ) and this is my first question here. So, i'm making a simple program where the user can input a number of data. This data is in struct, that has name, address, date of birth and phone number.

Then, in menu 2, the program will show all the inputed data

In 3rd menu, the program will show only 1/single data, for example only show the name of 2nd data

The problem is in 4th menu, i want the program to delete the data that user wants to delete. for example, if the user only wants to delete "name", user only need to type "name" in the program, then the program will delete all already inputed name in the struct. ( You can see it in the source code that i attached below, i already made comment in english )

As you can see my english is not really that great, and there are some non english language in this program, like the variable,etc. I'll do my best to explain if needed.

So, how can i delete data that user want?
Thanks for the help, appriciate it a lot

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define max 100
#include<stdbool.h>
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct identitas // STRUCT FOR DATA, 
{
    char nama [11]; // NAME
    char alamat [11]; // ADDRESS
    char tanggal_lahir[12]; // DATE OF BIRTH
    char nomor_telepon[13]; // PHONE NUMBER
};
    
int main () {
    struct identitas arr_identitas[max];
    struct identitas*ptr;
    int x,i = 1,choice,f,pilih,a=0,b,r ;
    while (1) {
        printf ("\n \t -*-*-*-*-* WELCOME TO MENU -*-*-*-*-* \t \n"); // MAIN MENU
        printf("\n");
        printf ("1. Memasukkan/Menambahkan Data \n"); // 1. INPUT INITIAL DATA
        printf("2. Menampilkan data \n"); // 2. SHOWING DATA (ALL)
        printf("3. Menampilkan 1 data \n"); // 3. SHOWING DATA (1/SINGLE)
        printf("4. Menghapus data \n"); // 4. DELETING DATA
        printf ("5. Menginput tambahan \n"); //5. INPUTING ADDITIONAL DATA
        printf ("6. Mengedit data \n"); // 6. EDIT EXISTING DATA
        printf("7. Exit\n\n\n"); // 7. EXITING DATA
        printf("Enter your choice :  "); scanf("%d",&choice);
            
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1: // ==> Inputing data from user
            printf ("Masukkan Jumlah Data : "); scanf("%d", &x); // Input max number of data
        
            ptr = calloc (x, sizeof (arr_identitas[max])) ;
            if (ptr == 0) { 
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n"); 
                exit(0); 
            }
            else {
                printf("Memory array  successfully allocated \n");
            }
        
            while (i <= x ) {
                printf ("Data ke = %d \n ",i);
                bool err=true;
                bool frr=true;
                int counter = 0;
                while (counter == 0) {
                    fflush(stdin);
                    printf ("Masukkan nama anda : "); gets((ptr+i)->nama);
                    if ( strlen ((ptr+i)->nama ) == 0 ) {
                        printf("# ERROR,TERMINATE PROGRAM # \n");
                        exit(0);
                    }
                    else {
                        counter = 1;
                    }
                }   
                printf ("Masukkan alamat anda : "); gets((ptr+i)->alamat);
            
                printf ("Masukkan kode telp anda (xxxx-xxxxxxxxx) : "); gets ((ptr+i)->nomor_telepon);
                while(err==true){
                    if((ptr+i)->nomor_telepon[3]!='-'&&(ptr+i)->nomor_telepon[4]!='-'){
                        printf("EROR COBA LAGI.\n");
                        printf("Masukkan kode telp anda (xxxx-xxxxxxxxx): "); gets((ptr+i)->nomor_telepon);
                    }
                    else err=false;
                }
                
                printf ("Masukkan tanggal lahir anda (dd/mm/yyyy) : "); gets ((ptr+i)->tanggal_lahir);
                while(frr==true){
                    if((ptr+i)->tanggal_lahir[2]!='/'||(ptr+i)->tanggal_lahir[5]!='/'){
                        printf("ERROR COBA LAGI.\n");
                        printf("Masukkan tanggal lahir anda (dd/mm/yyyy) : \n\n"); gets((ptr+i)->tanggal_lahir);
                    }
                    else frr=false;
                }
                b = i;
                i++;
                counter = 0;
            }
            break;
                    
        case 2 : // ==> Showing inputed data from user
            for(i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
                printf("nama ke - %d, adalah : %s \n",i,(ptr+i)->nama);
                printf("alamat ke - %d, adalah : %s \n",i,(ptr+i)->alamat);
                printf ("Tanggal lahir yang anda inputkan : %s \n",(ptr+i)->tanggal_lahir);
                printf ("No telp yang anda masukkan : %s \n\n",(ptr+i)->nomor_telepon);
            }
            break;
                    
        case 3 : // ==> Switch Case Menu too look for which single data
            printf ("\t\t -*-*-*-*-* MENU PILIHAN DATA YANG INGIN DILIHAT -*-*-*-*-* \n\n");
            printf ("1. Data Nama \n");
            printf ("2. Data Alamat \n");
            printf ("3. Data Nomor Telepon \n");
            printf ("4. Data Tanggal Lahir \n");
            printf ("Enter your choice : "); scanf("%d",&f);
                    
            switch (f)
            {
            case 1 : // if single data is name
                while (a == 0){
                                
                    printf ("Data nama ke ? = "); scanf ("%d",&pilih);
                    if (pilih > 0 && pilih <= b) {
                        printf("\t \t Nama ke - %d, adalah : %s",pilih,(ptr+pilih)->nama);
                        printf("\n");
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ("DATA GA ADA, COBA LAGI \n");
                    }
                }
                break;
                        
                            
            case 2 : // if single data is address
                a = 0;
                while (a==0) {
                    printf ("Data Alamat ke ? = "); scanf ("%d",&pilih);
                    if (pilih > 0 && pilih <= b) {
                        printf("\t \t Alamat ke - %d, adalah : %s", pilih, (ptr+pilih)->alamat);
                        printf("\n");
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ("DATA GA ADA, COBA CARI LAGI \n ");
                    }
                }
                break;
                            
            case 3 : // if single data is phone number
                a = 0;
                while (a==0) {
                    printf("Data Nomor Telepon ke ? = "); scanf ("%d",&pilih);
                    if (pilih > 0 && pilih <= b) {
                        printf("\t \t Nomor Telepon ke - %d, adalah : %s", pilih, (ptr+pilih)->nomor_telepon);
                        printf("\n");
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        printf ("DATA GA ADA, COBA CARI LAGI \n");
                    }
                }
                break;
                            
            case 4 : //if single data is date of birth
                a = 0;
                while (a == 0) {
                    printf("Data Tanggal lahir ke? = "); scanf ("%d",&pilih);
                    if (pilih > 0 && pilih <= b) {
                        printf("\t \t Tanggal lahir ke - %d, adalah : %s \n", pilih, (ptr+pilih)->tanggal_lahir);
                        printf("\n");
                        a = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        printf ("DATA GA ADA, COBA CARI LAGI \n \n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
                    
        case 4 :// deletion data code ==> problem!!
            a = 0;
            while (a == 0) {
                printf ("Menghapus data apa = "); scanf ("%d",&r); //asking user what data want to be deleted
                for (r = ; r<x; r++) { //searching for the data
                    ptr[pilih].nama = ptr[pilih+1];  //deleting data?? STILL PROBLEMATIC
                    x--;
                }
                break;
            }
            break;
            
        case 5 :
            printf ("not yet implemented\n");
            break;
                
        case 6 :
            printf("not yet implemented\n");
            break;
                
        case 7 :
            printf("\n\n\t\t\t# TERIMA KASIH #\n\n\n"); // THANK YOU SCREEN
            exit(0);
        
        }       
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up i know the code in menu/case 4 is not completed, cause im stuck and didnt know the code ^^ that's why i ask here

Comment: best time to learn functions , for a start you can refer [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/functions-in-c#:~:text=Function%20Aspects%20%20%20%20SN%20%20,%20%20return_type%20function_name%20%28argument%20list%20...%20) and [here](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-functions)